# Collect data from a particular column in Angular table

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, html-table, formgroups

I have a table that uses an array to populate its rows. The ‘Value’ column has input fields to insert some data. So what I need to know is how can I collect all the data on ‘Value’ column after inserting data? Can I use ‘formGroup’, or is there anything similar to that? Please note, the number of rows always change based on the array size. Really appreciate your help. Thank you.

[image]

Component.ts file

```
export class AppComponent {
 members = [
   {
     dataLimit: 'Package 1: Voice',
     value: 0,
     uom: 'Minutes',
   },
   {
     dataLimit: 'Package 2: SMS',
     value: 0,
     uom: 'Units',
   },
 ];
}
```

HTML file

```
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Unit of Mesure</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let member of members">
        <td>{{ member.dataLimit }}</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="{{ member.value }}" /></td>
        <td>{{ member.uom }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely right!  I leave you the code running with a form getting the values in [**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vis99u?file=src/app/app.component.html), so you can verify it and make your tests easily.

Just as you say, you can use a *FormGroup* to make that, using an **Angular ReactiveForm**:

1. First, be sure you have loaded the ReactiveForm Module in the module (AppModule in your example) of the component in which you want the form (AppComponent in your example):

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';  
@NgModule({  
imports: [  
 // other imports ...  
ReactiveFormsModule  
 ],  
})  
export class AppModule { }
```

2. In your component, declare your form and "built" it, generating dinamically a field for every row of your table:

```
import { Component, OnInit, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;

  members = [
    {
      dataLimit: 'Package 1: Voice',
      value: 0,
      uom: 'Minutes',
    },
    {
      dataLimit: 'Package 2: SMS',
      value: 0,
      uom: 'Units',
    },
  ];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const myFields = this.buildFormFieldsFormGroup();
    console.log('myFields: ', myFields);

    this.form = myFields;
  }

  private buildFormFieldsFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    const membersLength = this.members.length;
    let response: FormGroup = this.fb.group({ dummy: ['', []] });

    for (let i = 0; i < membersLength; i++) {
      response.addControl(`field${i}`, new FormControl());
    }
    console.log('response: ', response);

    return response;
  }
}
```

3. Add the form and formControls to your HTML:

```
<div>
  <form [formGroup]="form">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Value</th>
      <th>Unit of Mesure</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let member of members, let i=index">
      <td>{{ member.dataLimit }}</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="{{ member.value }}" formControlName="field{{i}}" /></td>
      <td>{{ member.uom }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

4. If you want to test that it is working fine, add this at the end of your HTML:

```
FORM VALUE: {{ form.value | json }}
```

As a result, when you insert some values in the table, you would see its values in the corresponding field, as you can see in this image:
[image]

You have the value of the first row in the form, in its "field0" field, and so on...
(NOTE: I leave the 'dummy' field in the form because I needed it to create the "seed" form, to give you a quick response... When I get time I will improve the code creating the form without using it, but for now, it doesn't bother and the form is fully functional)